# How to write all class variables to disk with dill?

Tags: python, pickle, dill

I'm trying to store a couple of objects for restart purposes in a code I'm writing. They are fairly complex, with several layers of classes contained within them, including classes that use class variables. I need this all to be restored when I dill.load() it back up.

Unfortunately, there's a very specific thing that I'm doing that seems to not work with dill.

I've created a test case that exhibits the problem:

basic.py:

```
class Basic(object):
    x = 10
    def __init__(self, initial=False):
        super(Basic, self).__init__()
        self.y = 4
        Basic.z = 5
```

make_dill.py:

```
import dill
from basic import Basic
b = Basic()
with open('basic', 'wb') as f:
    dill.dump(b, f)
with open('basic', 'rb') as f:
    b = dill.load(f)
print('basic', b.x, b.y, b.z)
```

un_dill.py:

```
import dill
with open('basic', 'rb') as f:
    b = dill.load(f)
print('basic', b.x, b.y, b.z)
```

It works fine when it is all run from the same file (make_dill.py), but when I try to read the file basic in un_dill.py:

```
AttributeError: 'Basic' object has no attribute 'z'
```

So for some reason it isn't capturing the class variable z that is assigned during initialization of an instance. It does however capture the class variable x that is assigned right in the class definition.

What am I missing here? I need to save the complete state of these objects.

In the sparse dill documentation, it says

> In addition to pickling python objects, dill provides the ability to save the state of an interpreter session in a single command.

but I can't figure out how to do that.

Comment: `Basic.z = 5` is  a horrible line. Don't do that.

Comment: It looks like ``dump_session()``/``load_session()`` are the functions you want.

Comment: @xaav I believe you, but do you want to explain why that's bad? I'm using this construct to save an initial state of the the class so that it is available for all future instances to refer to without passing it around constantly. Is there some better way to accomplish this?

Comment: The `__init__` method is only supposed to affect changes in the object instance. Only class methods should change the class definition. If you need to calculate the class definition at runtime, you should use a metaclass.

Comment: @jasonharper thanks for that. Unfortunately it does the same thing as storing the objects manually.

Comment: @xaav Alright, thanks for the info. Sounds like I have more reading to do.

Comment: Using the `Basic.z` construct is dynamically adding a class attribute in the initialization of the class instance.  That to me screams bad coding practice... however, a serializer shouldn't be judgmental, and should handle it.  `dill` doesn't, and none of the alternate serializers do either.  The issue is in how the class object is stored in the serializer -- it stores the class definition, literally -- but it can store other stuff.  Thus, in some cases, you will lose dynamically added attributes... and this is one of those cases.  I suggest you submit a ticket  for `dill` on it's github page.