# Store initial instance of class for access by all future instances

Tags: python, pickle, dill

I have an application where I'd like to make the first instance of a class available for access by all subsequent instances of that class. I implemented this like:

```
class Basic(object):
    def __init__(self, initial=False):
        super(Basic, self).__init__()
        if initial:
            Basic.initial = self
```

It works nicely, but when I try to serialize it with `pickle` or `dill`, the dynamically created class attribute `Basic.initial` does not serialize properly ([How to write all class variables to disk with dill?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42752716/how-to-write-all-class-variables-to-disk-with-dill)).

I've been told that what I'm doing is "bad" and I can understand that because it does seem kinda roundabout.

I want that first instance to be available for use in all future instances without passing it around constantly.

Is there a better way to accomplish this? Maybe one that will serialize properly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a singleton in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6760685/creating-a-singleton-in-python)

Comment: Maybe it isn't a dupe... but I believe if you go with the metaclass approach it will fix your pickle issue. But my advice is not to use singletons, just use a module.

Comment: I tried doing a metaclass and any class attribute created with `__call__` had the same serialization problem. Also I couldn't figure out how to store the instance of the class instead of the class object itself using a metaclass.

Comment: Well, the good news is you probably just want to use a module, and ditch the class anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up making a module that is something like this:

```
class BasicInit(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(BasicInit, self).__init__()

    def read(self):
        #read some stuff from files...

    def work(self):
        #do whatever work

initial_thing = BasicInit()
initial_thing.read()

class Basic(BasicInit):
    initial = initial_thing
    def __init__(self):
        super(Basic, self).__init__()
```

And while that again seems roundabout, it seems to work.

Maybe there's a more elegant solution?